# django template not show ForeignKey items

Tags: django

I'm new to django I'm having a problem with my foreignkey items not displaying hope you can help me... thank you.

here's my models.py

```
class Reporter(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class News(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

and my views.py

```
def index(request):

    reportlist = Reporter.objects.all()

    context = {
        'reportlist': reportlist
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and my template

```
{% block content %}

    {% for r in reportlist %}
    <p>{{r.name}}</p>
    {% for items in r.item_set.all%}
         <p>{{items.headline}}</p>
            {%endfor%} <br/>
    {%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it should be `{% for items in r.news_set.all%}` in your template. From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: if i add prefetch_related is this still gonna work?

Comment: prefetch_related wont work in template. You need to use that in your views

Answer (score 1):

```
{% block content %}

    {% for r in reportlist %}
    <p>{{r.name}}</p>
    {% for items in r.news_set.all%}
         <p>{{items.headline}}</p>
            {%endfor%} <br/>
    {%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

your model name is `News` so you need `model_name_set`, i.e. `news_set`